# How to export DGN with color in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, dgn

I have some polygons with defined colors according to a column in attribute table. I need an example about how to export these polygons into a DGN file with the color but I can't find any after Google Search. Is this possible in QGIS?

I have python background. So if your answer requires some programming, I can take it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have microstation to test the results, but you can export your polygon data to DGN. `Right-click the layer -> Export -> Save Feature As -> select Microstation DGN`:

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that this answer works for me. To export the symbology you just need to change the "Symbology export" dropdown to "Feature symbology".